# Netbeans 8.0.2 запуск на выполение файла по shift+F6

Tags: netbeans

Подскажите как запустить на выполение отдельный файл из проекта на C. Комбинация клавиш shift+F6 не активна. Проект возможно только полностью запустить по F6,а мне нужно именно один файл. Как это сделать?

Comment: Как вы себе представляете "запуск" одного файла из проекта? Это всё равно, что выломать из машины одну педаль и пытаться поехать на ней :)

Comment: я только начал изучать С, проект создан что бы там вводить примеры из книги. Правильно я понял, что для каждого примера нужно будет создавать новый проект?

Comment: Если чуть упростить, то один проект - одна исполняемая единица (которая, правда, может состоять из большого количества разных файлов)